# Error en Lectura de Huella: Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con un lector de huella dactilar U ARE U 4500 Digital Persona en Visual Studio con C#, pero al momento de escanear una huella me marca este error

> Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8

Ya busque por todos lados y no encuentro respuesta, ni nada que me diga que significa ese error. Este es el código que hice:

```
   private void VerificationControl1_OnComplete(object Control, DPFP.FeatureSet FeatureSet, ref DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus EventHandlerStatus)
    {
        Boolean TerminarBucle = false;            
        Template template1 = new Template();
        Template template2 = new Template();
        Template template3 = new Template();
        Template template4 = new Template();
        Template template5 = new Template();
        int xint = 1;
        byte[] fingerprint1;
        byte[] fingerprint2;
        byte[] fingerprint3;
        byte[] fingerprint4;
        byte[] fingerprint5;
        int idEmpleado = 0;
        string NombreE;            

        foreach (DataRow item in Emp.Rows)//Aqui recorro el datatable que contiene las huellas
        {
            if (TerminarBucle == true) return;

            idEmpleado = Convert.ToInt32(item["IdEmpleado"].ToString());
            NombreE = item["Nombre"].ToString();
            fingerprint1 = (byte[])item["TemplateHuella1"];
            fingerprint2 = (byte[])item["TemplateHuella2"];
            fingerprint3 = (byte[])item["TemplateHuella3"];
            fingerprint4 = (byte[])item["TemplateHuella4"];
            fingerprint5 = (byte[])item["TemplateHuella5"];

            template1.DeSerialize(fingerprint1);
            template2.DeSerialize(fingerprint2);
            template3.DeSerialize(fingerprint3);
            template4.DeSerialize(fingerprint4);
            template5.DeSerialize(fingerprint5);

            verificar1.Verify(FeatureSet, template1, ref resultado1);//Aqui me marca el error, se supone que aqui me compara la huella que tengo almacenada en la base de datos y la que obtengo del lector
            verificar2.Verify(FeatureSet, template2, ref resultado2);
            verificar3.Verify(FeatureSet, template3, ref resultado3);
            verificar4.Verify(FeatureSet, template4, ref resultado4);
            verificar5.Verify(FeatureSet, template5, ref resultado5);

            try//y aqui le digo que si las huellas coinciden me muestre la foto y el nombre de la persona
            {
                if (resultado1.Verified == true || resultado2.Verified == true || resultado3.Verified == true || resultado4.Verified == true || resultado5.Verified == true)
                {
                    pFotoEmp.Image = publico.BytesAImagen((byte[])item["Fotografia"]);
                    lNombreEmp.Text = item["Nombre"].ToString();
                    //MostrarDetalleAsistencias(idEmpleado);

                    int BTA = biss.BuscarTipoAsistencia(idEmpleado);
                    //verificamos si ya checo entrada y salida
                    if (BTA == 1)
                    {
                        if (biss.VerificarUltimaAsistencia(idEmpleado))
                        {
                            biss.ChecarSalida(idEmpleado, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                            MessageBox.Show("La salida se ha checado", "Mensage", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            biss.ChecarEntrada(idEmpleado, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"));
                            MessageBox.Show("La entrada se ha checado", "Mensage", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                    }
                }
                TerminarBucle = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Algo malo paso " + ex.Message, "Advertencia de Seguridad", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                TerminarBucle = true;
            }
        }`
```

Ya le he modificado todo como he visto en otros foros y me sigue dando el mismo error. Incluso pregunte si el tamaño de los datos que estan guardados tenian algo que ver con ese error, pero me dijeron que no.

Comment: El lector de huella tiene alguna libreria ? Podria ser que estan repitiendo huellas o no se este colocando correctamente la huella

Comment: si te fijas bien en el codigo adentro de try tengo un if donde indico que si resultado = true entonces me checa la asistencia, pero si no, no hace nada, se me olvido porner un mensaje y un else

Comment: te refieres a esto: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Excepción de HRESULT: 0xFFFFFFF8''

Comment: No,me refiero a que si te captura en el catch la excepcion, trates de consultar `ex.InnerException`.

Comment: me arroja el mismo error

Comment: No he trabajado nunca con esa librería, asi que no creo que pueda ayudarte demasiado. Sospecho que el problema está en alguno de los parámetros que pasas al `Verify`. Revisa la documentación para ver que tipos de parámetro y que datos deben recibir. Revisa tambien como está definido `resultado1`, al ser pasado por referencia puede provocar problemas si está como private por ejemplo, y cosas asi. Suerte

Comment: Yo he usado esa librería, si estas de acuerdo en probar, podrías inicialmente probar lo siguiente ...cambia estas lienas de codigo ->  fingerprintN = (byte[])item["TemplateHuellaN"];aqui cambia (byte[])item por (byte[])row

Comment: pero porque row, si en el foreach que hago para recorrer la tabla tengo item, seria lo mismo, no?